# update distance matrix between n points

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to update a $N*N$ matrix, in which the coefficients represents the distance between $N$ number of points, every time that the coordinates of a point change in a 2D Cartesian plane.

Here an example:
There are 3 points in a Cartesian plane:

$a=(1,3)$
$b=(3,3)$
$c=(4,1)$

to calculate the distance between $a$ and $b$ I would simply apply:

$d_{ab} = \sqrt{(x_b-x_a)^2 + (y_b-y_a)^2}$

the distance matrix would be a $3*3$ diagonal matrix where the coefficients represent the distances between each point:

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & d_{ab} & d_{ac} \\ d_{ba} & 0 & d_{bc} \\ d_{ca} & d_{cb} & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

My algorithm is pretty straight forward: I nest 2 `for` loops to calculate the distance between each point that are inside the points `array` every time a coordinate change.
Here an example in python, but I am not interested in a language specific solution:

```python
import math
def distance(a,b):
    x = pow(b[0]-a[0], 2)
    y = pow(b[1]-a[1], 2)
    return math.sqrt(x+y)

points = [[1,3],[3,3],[4,1]]; # cartesian points
distanceMatr = [];
matrixLen = len(points);
for i in range(matrixLen):
    point = points[i]
    row = []
    for j in range(matrixLen):
        d = distance(point, points[j])
        row.append(d)

    distanceMatr.append(row)

print(distanceMatr)
```

If now $a$ moves to $(2,3)$ `points` becomes `[[2,3],[3,3],[4,1]]` and I apply the same algorithm again.

The main problems that I would like to optimise of this algorithm are:

- if the coordinates of $a$ change the distance between $b$ and $c$ doesn't
- the distance $d_{ab}$ is equal to $d_{ba}$
- the distance between $a$ and itself is always $0$

Do you have any advice?
thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If the coordinates of $a$ change, you just need to update one row and one column corresponding to $a$, not the whole matrix. This is done in linear time rather than quadratic time in your algorithm.